# How to check if Value of an array is true in a cell(Google Script)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am having issues checking if the string value in my array is true in a cell.

```
function myFunction() {
 var People  = ['Amanda', 'John'];
for (var n in People )
{
if( People[0] == true);

Logger.log("BOOKED");
}
 else{
 Logger.log("FREE"); 
}

}
```

Comment: Read about JavaScript equality comparisons and type conversions.

Comment: Your primary issue is caused by an extra `;` which creates what is known as an "empty loop body".

Answer (score -1):

Plenty of issues with the code!

Does this do it ?

```
function myFunction() {
 var People  = ['Amanda', 'John'];

 for (var n=0;n<People.length;n++) {

   if( People[n] ) {

    Logger.log("BOOKED");
   }
   else {
   Logger.log("FREE"); 
   }
 }
}
```

I'm not sure if you just want to test for members of the array being present, or if you want to test actual names in the array

Comment: OP's problem is an empty loop body caused by a typo. That's worthy of a comment, not an answer (and you don't even state the issues you fix, so this answer is not even helpful to OP).